# Can i use AWS KMS with react native?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-kms

I am new to aws i have gone through https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/KMS.html this link

it is difficult  to understand

If anyone has did kms with react native can you share how you did ?

thank you in advance

Comment: Your post does not contain an exact question, seems like waiting for sample code as a solution. What have you tried so far?